# updating Input value behaving weirdly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I got 2 ASPX controls

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbValue" MaxLength="18" Enabled="false" />

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdtbValue" />
```

In Client side when javascript function called to change values to both for same value. its rendered as

[image]

In Console, when i check `document.getElementById(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbValue).value` its `YYYYY` not `XXXXX` which is confusing me as innerHTML value is still pre-calculated figure of `XXXXX` while property value in browser **console** is `YYYYY` this is failing my ASP.NET validator as its picking up old value

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvtbValue" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="valNumericValue" ValidateEmptyText="true" ControlToValidate="tbValue" />
```

while changing input value of hiddenField working, its not for ASP:TextBox?

changing input value

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked out by using following to update value:
document.getElementById(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbValue).setAttribute('value', calculatedValue);

This still won't persist on PostBack, so need to assign from HiddenField value in codeBehind PostBack